# Data Loader - 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: data-loader

I have just started uploading some data using data loader. The first 6000 records were uploaded correctly, but then I receveived a `407 Proxy Authentication Required` error.

I am not sure what happened here?

[image: 407 Proxy Authentication Required]

Any ideas?
Tia, Lily.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set proxy port and proxy host in the dataloader settings.

Comment: they are set. the strange thing is that it loads nearly half the records and then i get the error.

Comment: @Lily, Try to check Use Bulk API this is the setting for large data loads.

Comment: Thanks Viktor - I used the Bulk API, but then I get only errors.

Comment: @Lily, what errors?